# How to Create web server on the windows 10 IOT core

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-iot-core

I have a device with windows 10 IOT core. I need to host a web app on this device so any can connect and use that pages with local network.

Comment: There is always a web server running on the OS to support its operational management features. Go to it's IP address and port 8080. Then maybe dig into how this is setup.

Comment: Though there's a lot of possible answers, one of which is to use node.js, check on https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/12/bringing-node-js-to-windows-10-iot-core/#I2Jkucx5tk1xEjfI.97

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution here using node js :

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldnode

Comment: Awesome. As an extra, here is a tutorial for deploying asp.net web application. https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4

Comment: I see, hope someone will find it useful.